# Proving Mantel's theorem by removing only a single vertex

Tags: graph-theory

Mantel's theorem says that a triangle-free graph has at most $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges.

Many proofs exist, including the following proof by induction: We consider an arbitrary edge $(x,y)$ and remove both vertices $x$ and $y$. We are left with a graph on at most $\frac{(n-2)^2}4$ edges, and we removed at most $n-1$ edges since $d(x)+d(y)\leq n$. So $m \leq \frac{(n-2)^2}4 + (n-1)=\frac{n^2}4$.

In this proof we removed two vertices from our graph, since the assumption on triangle-freeness constraints their sum of degrees. Alas, this assumption does not constrain the degree of a single vertex. How can we prove Mantel's theorem by induction removing only *a single vertex*?

The lecturer told us to "think of a fix" that would allow us to use induction in this way, but the original method cannot work since $\frac{n^2}4-\frac{(n-1)^2}4=\frac{2n-1}{4}$ is not a bound on the number of edges removed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the maximum degree in the graph is $D$.

If $D \leq \frac{n}{2}$ then we are done, so suppose $D > \frac{n}{2}$. Let $v$ be a vertex of degree $D$ and let $w$ be the neighbor of $v$ with the smallest degree.

Can you prove that $w$ has small enough degree to finish the induction proof?

Comment: Sorry.  How should the specific follow-up steps be shown?

Comment: Maybe I know.  Now $w$ is of degree at most $\frac{n}{2}$ since $G$ is  triangle-free . Vote up.